# How to dynamically use a string value as key type in return object in order to have proper typings?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a higher order function that will inject a key / value into an object and return it.

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

const withPrimaryKey = (key: string) => <T>(input: T) => {
    return {
        ...input,
        [key]: uuid()
    }
}

export default withPrimaryKey;
```

In usage, it would look like this:

```
const injectPrimaryKey = withPrimaryKey('categoryId');

const input = {
  name: 'books'
};

const data = injectPrimaryKey(input);

console.log(data); // { categoryId: '25b9dea6-5856-4c53-bfef-c2505eacae15', name: 'books' }
```

As is, it works fine.. however the typings of the returned `data` object does not indicate that `categoryId` exists. And doing the following throws a Typescript error:

```
const data: typeof input & { categoryId: string } = insertPrimaryKey(input);
```

> Property 'categoryId' is missing in type [...]

How do I properly type my `withPrimaryKey` function in order to dynamically include `categoryId` and if that is not possible, what's the next best thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `key` type to generic and use type assertion for return value (without type assertion `K` is widened to `string`):

```
const withPrimaryKey = <K extends string>(key: K) => <T>(input: T) => {
    return {
        [key]: uuid(),
        ...input,
    } as Record<K, string> & T
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgNwCxwIYGc4FdfAAmcAvnAGZQQhwDk%20RtA3AFAsDGEAdlvAO7AYACwAKUUBigBPANIBTKXAC8cADwy4cgB4w5XQjl7iuAcwB8ACgDWCgFxwZASmVm1AFUvAuYXDHtvnJVcEFjg4KDkYXCguRFCwuABtGykAXXsGQgtHABp4sIA6Iq8fGDywsmw4ACU5TihCdRy4Iy9zOAAyODcWEjZOHngvACs6mDEJaXlFFQFhCZBJWQULWnYMXRNoKQBJQlpHVg5uXjgS32U4sK4MEDl7WgAjCAgrLFpeo4HTwg2MS5GYwWS2mFnOMEObF%20MAwBXWm22exY0NhNzuUL%20BXILzgAHpcXAAKJaMBjOTEORQKhQIA)